# Need Help in fixing "Minimum" output. Also, altering the code by not using Arrays.sort

Tags: arrays, loops, minimum

I would like to be helped in fixing the "Minimum" Output and Altering      the code without using Arrays.sort Just some clue will be fine.

```
package newempty;
import java.util.*;
public class NewEmpty{
public static void main (String args []){
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
int bry [] = new int [5];
int high = bry[0];
int low = bry[0];
for (int i = 0; i < bry.length; i++){
  System.out.print("Enter a Number: ");
  bry[i] = in.nextInt();
}
System.out.print("Ascending Order: ");
for (int i = 0; i<bry.length; i++){
  high = bry [i] > high ? bry[i]:high;
  Arrays.sort(bry);
  System.out.print(" " + bry[i]);
}
System.out.print("\nDescending Order: ");
for (int i = bry.length-1; i>=0; i--){
  low = bry [i] < low ? bry[i]:low;
  Arrays.sort(bry);
  System.out.print(" " + bry[i]);
}
System.out.println("\nMinimum: " + low);
System.out.println("Maximum: " + high);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't sort the array while you are in the middle of looping through it!

```
for (int i = bry.length-1; i>=0; i--){
  low = bry [i] < low ? bry[i]:low;
  Arrays.sort(bry);
  System.out.print(" " + bry[i]);
}
```

And you don't have to sort it over and over again. Once is sufficient. Once it is sorted, it is sorted. Additionally, once you have sorted it, you don't have to go searching for the min and max values. They are at the beginning and end of the list, respectively.

Do this instead:

```
Arrays.sort(bry);
low = bry[0];
high = bry[bry.length-1];
System.out.print("Ascending Order: ");
for (int i = 0; i < bry.length; i++){
  System.out.print(" " + bry[i]);
}
System.out.println();
System.out.print("Descending Order: ");
for (int i = bry.length-1; i>=0; i--){
  System.out.print(" " + bry[i]);
}
```

On a totally unrelated note, forget right now that "\n" is newline. That is not true. \n is newline in Unixland. \r\n is newline in Windows land. Older Macs use \r as newline. Some other systems even use \n\r.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

You will have headaches later if you assume \n is newline everywhere. In this case, you can just ask for a println, but you can also get in the habit of asking for:

```
 String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

That will give you whatever newline is appropriate for the system the code is running on.